# nested dicts(how to print all keys and columns)

Tags: python

The below is a dictionary/JSON, i want to separate each key and value in a different column and put it in the excel.

```
expected Output:
Keys                      Values
h                             e
f                              r
t                              ['w', 'x']
P                             ['d', 'c']
l  

                         q
```

I tried

```
import json

x = {
  "a": [
      { "h":"e" }, { "f": "r" }, { "t":  "[ w, x ]" } ],
  "b": [
      {"P": "[ d, c ]" }, {"l": "q" } ]
}

print(json.dumps(x))

for k, v in x.items():
    for k1, v1 in v.items():
        print(k1)
```

Comment: What exactly is the question?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With slight modification in your example:

```
    for k, v in x.items():
        for item in v:
            for k1, v1 in item.items():
                print(f'{k1}  {v1}')
```

Answer (score 0):

```
import json

x = {
  "a": [
      { "h":"e" }, { "f": "r" }, { "t":  "[ w, x ]" } ],
  "b": [
      {"P": "[ d, c ]" }, {"l": "q" } ]
}

print(json.dumps(x))

for k, v in x.items():
    for v1 in v:
       print(v1.values())
```

I belive this is that you want, your values in the first dictionary have lists inside it, so you need to loop through them and then get the values

Answer (score 0):

create one dictionary from desired keys and value and then you can use pandas DataFrame to create dataframe from dictionary

> Data frame is a two-dimensional data structure, i.e., data is aligned
>   in a tabular fashion in rows and columns. Pandas DataFrame consists of
>   three principal components, the data, rows, and columns.

```
import pandas as pd
x = {
  "a": [
      { "h":"e" }, { "f": "r" }, { "t":  "[ w, x ]" } ],
  "b": [
      {"P": "[ d, c ]" }, {"l": "q" } ]
}

data = {}
for v in x.values():
    for item in v:
        data.update(item)

df =(pd.DataFrame(list(data.items()), columns=['Key', 'Value']))
print (df.to_string(index = False))
```

output:

```
Key     Value
  h         e
  f         r
  t  [ w, x ]
  P  [ d, c ]
  l         q
```